# Where can I find some examples of databases created in C using struct?

Tags: c, database, pointers, struct

I've been given an assignment in college where I need to create a database in C using struct, the database's structure is as following:

---

### Student

- Name

  - Name
  - Last name
- Semester

  - Courses taken that semester
  - - Name of said course
  - - Grade
  - - Credits granted by this course

---

One important thing is that every semester, any student can go through any given number of courses.

Right now I'm stuck since the requirements are the following:

- I should be able to update any student's information
- Edit their grades and also calculate the number of credits using a different file where it states how many credits each course grants.
- Search for a student

I am pretty familiarized with pointers and structures, I'm looking for examples of similar databases in C because I haven't grasped the concept of how should I add/update/delete Students in my database, hell i don't even know how to properly store them! 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what I've wrote so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct UDA {
    char clave[9];
    char nombre[125];
} UDA;

typedef struct NOMBRE{
    char N[100];
} NOMBRE;

typedef struct PERIODO{
    UDA *uda;
} PERIODO;

typedef struct ALUMNO{
    int nua;
    NOMBRE nombre;
    PERIODO *periodo;
} ALUMNO;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int s, d;
    FILE *clave;
    FILE *alumi;

    ALUMNO student;

    switch (argc) {
        case 3:
            clave = fopen(argv[1], "r");
            alumi = fopen(argv[2], "a+");
            break;
        case 2:
            if(argv[1][0] == 'c'){
                clave = fopen(argv[1], "r");
                alumi = fopen("alumnos.txt", "a+");
                fprintf(alumi, "0\n");
            } else {
                printf("ERROR\nArchivos faltantes\n");
                return 0;
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            clave = fopen("claves.txt", "r");
            alumi = fopen("alumnos.txt", "a+");
            fprintf(alumi, "0\n");
            break;
    }

    do{
        printf("Desea:\n1. Agregar alumno\n2. Actualizar alumno\n3. Eliminar alumno\n4. Mostrar informacion de un alumno\n\t> ");
        scanf("%d", &d);
    } while(d<1 || d>4);

    switch (d) {
        case 1:
            getchar();
            printf("Ingrese el nombre del alumno: ");
            scanf("%[^\n]", student.nombre.N);
            fprintf(alumi, "%s\n", student.nombre.N);

    }

    fclose(alumi);
    fclose(clave);
    return 0;
}
```

also here is two lines of the claves.txt which is the file that contains the course names.

```
NELI06001   Algebra Lineal
AGLIS4001   Analisis de Documentales en una Lengua Extranjera
```

Comment: show us some code

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Oh, and we are not a coding service either. If you are familiar with the elements as you state, you should be able to do your homework yourself.

Comment: Orel i've updated my post. @Olaf sorry for the ambiguity of my question, to be more specific I'd like to know how to re-write the whole file so I can edit the first character i write(0, the number of students in my database), since from what I've read it is more simple to do so than to change just that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your comment(if I understood it correctly) you can open 2 files naming one temp and start copying everything from file 1 to file 2 until you find what you want to change, change it and keep copying the rest renaming the "temp" file you created and removing the old one.

```
FILE *f, *g
f = open("alumnos.txt", "r"); // opens your main file
g = open("temp.txt", "w"); //opens your temporary file

.
. Copy from alumnos to temp and change the things you want to
.

fclose(f)
fclose(g)

remove("alumnos.txt") // old file without the changes
rename("temp.txt", "alumnos.txt") // renaming the new file with the changes
```

Just make sure things did in fact change before removing and renaming otherwise you'll be left with an empty file.